# Exception thrown when the DB doesn't exist yet and the application tries to create it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

This happens only, when there is no DB yet and it has to be created. Any ideas on how to fix this?

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." gets thrown here:

```
public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            using (var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); // The exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." gets thrown here.
```

The application stops somewhere in this class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApp.Models;
using WebApp.Services;


namespace WebApp.Razor
{
    public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Application DB context
        /// </summary>
        protected ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User manager - attached to application DB context
        /// </summary>
        protected UserManager<User> UserManager { get; set; }

        public CustomWebViewPage()
        {
            this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            this.UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
        }

        public User CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                var currentUser = this.UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                if (currentUser == null)
                {
                    currentUser = new User { Name = "", UserName = "", Email = "", Id = "" };
                }
                return currentUser;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @greenhoorn Any particular part?

Comment: I would recommend moving this logic to a base controller instead of extending razor but that would require you slightly changing your views. Otherwise, you would most likely need aggressive null checks against UserManager in your CustomWebViewPage.

Comment: @br4d So you mean that i will create a controller from which all other controllers would inherit? Sounds good. Microsoft should really do something to make this easier. My fear with the base controller is that i would forget to extend when i would create a new controller, but if this is the only "reasonable" way to do it, then this is how it will be. :)